# What's wrong with this observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: implementation?

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

In my UIScrollView subclass, I'm observing frame changes:

```
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:NULL];
```

My `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` implementation is as follows:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"frame"]) {
        [self adjustSizeAndScale];
    }
    if ([UIScrollView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:)]) {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context]; // Exception
    }
}
```

But I get exception with this code:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '<WLImageScrollView: 0x733a440; baseClass = UIScrollView; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7346500>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: frame
Observed object: <WLImageScrollView: 0x733a440; baseClass = UIScrollView; frame = (0 0; 320 416); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7346500>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
}
Context: 0x0'
```

Does it mean UIScrollView implements `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` but throws the above exception?

If so, how can I properly implement `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` so that I can both handle my interested changes and give superclass a chance to handle its interested changes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Edit: BJ Homer's answer is probably a better approach to take here; I forgot all about the context parameter!*

Even though calling the super implementation is by-the-book, it [seems like](http://www.innerexception.com/2009/10/uitableviewcontroller-and.html) calling `observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` on `UIKit` classes that don't actually observe the fields in question throws an `NSInternalInconsistency` exception (not the `NSInvalidArgumentException` you would get with an unrecognized selector). The key string in the exception that suggests this to me is "received but not handled".

As far as I know, there's no well-documented way to find out if an object observes another object on a given key path. There may be partially-documented ways such as the `-observationInfo` property which is said to carry information on the observers of an object, but you're on your own there—it's a `void *`.

So as I see it, you've got two options: either don't call the `super` implementation or use an `@try`/`@catch`/`@finally` block to ignore that specific type of `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. The second option is probably more future-proof, but I have a hunch that some detective work could get you more satisfying results via the first option.

Comment: The article you linked to is talking about another thing: the superclass does NOT implement observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:. But here as you can see from the code, UIScrollView does implement it, otherwise super method will not be called.

Comment: Even if it does implement the method, it might have code that detects unobserved keys and throws exceptions for them—thus the `NSInternalInconsistency` exception "received but not handled", which is different from the `NSInvalidArgumentException` "unrecognized selector sent to instance".

Comment: That's what I'm asking. So the default implementation of observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: in NSObject throws exception? If so, there is nothing we can do to detect whether superclass wants to be notified of key value changes, isn't there?

Comment: The implementation in some UIKit classes, at least, certainly seems to. My guess, then, is "no, there's no (safe) way to detect it". The safest way is probably to look for that exception in an `@try`. Off-the-record, I would say that you might try looking at the `-observationInfo` property of the object you're interested in (`self`) on the off chance that it might help you find out what keys the parent class is observing.

Comment: Thanks:) Do you mind improving your answer with your comments so I can accept it?

Comment: Why can't you just handle the keypaths for the objects for which you want to and let the UIScrollView handle the rest?

Comment: Because if you pass along an object/key path pair that `UIScrollView` doesn't know to observe, it won't just ignore it--it'll throw an exception. Note that in the original question, the asker wants a `UIScrollView` subclass to observe itself to catch certain `frame` changes, since there's no available API besides KVO for that. Given that there's no documented way to know for sure if an object is observing a given object/key path pair, one cannot determine which pairs will and won't throw, so the most correct answer is probably to pass everything and catch any exceptions that arise.

Comment: It's actually not hard to know if the message is meant for you... just look use the 'context' parameter.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. You've still got to pass along observations without your special context up to the superclass, and there may be pathological cases where that is unsafe to do in general, but that's a good starting point for sure.

Answer (score 17):

You should add a `context` value when you add the observer. In your `-observeValueForKeyPath` method, check the context parameter. If it is not the context you passed when you added the observer, then you know this message is not intended for your subclass, and you can safely pass it on to the superclass. If it *is* the same value, then you know it's intended for you, and you should not pass it on to super.

Like this:

```
static void *myContextPointer;

- (void)addSomeObserver {
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:&myContextPointer];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (context != &myContextPointer) {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
    }
    else {
        // This message is for me, do whatever I want with it.
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be better to do something like `static int myContext;` and then `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"frame" options:0 context:&myContext];`.  This way, the address pointed to is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Oh, you're right, it should absolutely be `&myContextPointer`, not just `myContextPointer`. But I don't see why an `int` would be any better than a `void *`.

Comment: Nothing better about using an int, I don't think.  It's just slightly shorter to type `static int myContext;` than to type `static void *myContext;`.  (-:  I guess you could say, also, that it let's the compiler remind you that you should be using `&myContext` rather than just `myContext`--if `myContext`'s type is `int` the compiler will warn that you're doing an incompatible integer to pointer conversion.

Comment: Honestly, I usually do `static void *myContext = &myContext;`, which is nice because then `myContext == &myContext`, and you can use either one. But I didn't feel like trying to explain that little mess in an answer mostly unrelated to the topic.

Comment: @BJHomer nice, I've never come across this `static void *myContext = &myContext;` thing but now it seems so obvious. Thanks!