# How to detect user input character in UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

How to detect user input character in UITextView?

For example:(in UITextView NOT UITextField)

when user input letter "a", trigger an event. when user input "do it", trigger another event.
or input "http://www.stackoverflow.com" trigger an event.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you try UITextFieldDelegate methods for that.

Comment: - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text it will fire for every  charter press in textView

Comment: @Narayana you are the first correct. Next time you can put the answer to "Answer field". Then I can tick you~  Thanks!

Answer (score -14, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSString * length;   
    NSString *currentString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
length = [currentString length];
if (length > 1)
{

    looprange = _looptext.text;
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Please ! "
                                        message:@"Insert Single Characters !!"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return NO;

}
}
```

Comment: Thats okay!! It was just a pattern, it would be changed as per your purpose of usage.

Comment: -1; the question explicitly asked for detecting content changes on a `UITextView` and *not* a `UITextField`. This is wrong and I don't know why the question asker accepted it. The analagous method in `UITextViewDelegate` is, as mentioned in other answers, `- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text` (and both may be inappropriate for the asker's use case; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event).

Comment: -1 Agreeing with @MarkAmery about the irrelevancy of the answer here.

Answer (score 27):

You can monitor the TextView content changes inside this delegate method and trigger necessary actions.

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    //Access the textView Content
    //From here you can get the last text entered by the user
    NSArray *stringsSeparatedBySpace = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    //then you can check whether its one of your userstrings and trigger the event
    NSString *lastString = [stringsSeparatedBySpace lastObject];
    if([lastString isEqualToString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"]) //add more conditions here
    {
          [self callActionMethod];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

This delegate will be called whenever a user presses  key

Try this :-

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([[textView.text stringByAppendingString:text] isEqualToString:@"a"])
    {
      //trigger 'a' operation
    }
    else if([[textView.text stringByAppendingString:text] isEqualToString:@"do it"])
    {
      //trigger do it operation
    }
    //Same conditions go on
}
```

Comment: You cannot just append text, you have to take into account the range of where the changes occurred.

Comment: This function is more useful than textViewDidChange function, especially in case user uses the suggestion, instead of entering with keyboard.

Answer (score 8):

**Working Swift 3 Solution**

First, add `UITextViewDelegate`

Then, set delegate in `viewDidLoad` like so, `self.testTextField.delegate = self`

And finally, call the function `textViewDidChange`, example below.

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    // Do the logic you want to happen everytime the textView changes
    // if string is == "do it" etc....

}
```

Comment: UITextFieldDelegate should be UITextViewDelegate