# one TextField to 6 others

Tags: ios, storyboard, textfield

Quick Question, I hope,

I have a `UITextFeild` that I want to type in an number and have that number populate into 6 other `UITextfield`s on the same VC.

The first textfiled is called `percentage goal` while the others are named `endmonth1year1percentage`, `endmonth2year1percentage`, `endmonth3year1percentage`, etc.

I am currently using iOS6 with storey board.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: you want to display same number in all the textfields when you enter the text in one textfield right?

Comment: Correct.  I am just starting out with 6 but later will end up with a little over 100 and don't want to type it all in.

Answer (score 1):

Detect the change in the first text field: [UITextField text change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event)

And then update the text property of other text fields you want to be populated.

Answer (score 0):

try like  this,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
//replace your textfield names here
textField1.text=textField.text;
textField2.text=textField.text;
textField3.text=textField.text;
textField4.text=textField.text;
textField5.text=textField.text;


return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So for the first `UITextField` you must set the delegate the class that is responsible with the display of the text fields (a view controller or a custom view). For the other `UITextFiled`s you should set a tag like 1,2,3..for each UITextFiled (because you say that will be lots of `UITextFields`)

After you set the delegate for the first `UITextField` and setup the tags, you can implement two different delegate methods (depending on what you want).

The method that *Sunny* provided, this is for instant changes:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
  for(int i = firstTextViewTag; i<=lastTextViewTag; i++) {
    UITextView *newTextView = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i]; 
    //or [yourCustomView viewWithTag:i]
    newTextView.text = textField.text;
  }

  return YES;
}
```

Second, you can use the following if you want to update the textfields only after the user finished typing and the keyboard is hidden:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  for(int i = firstTextViewTag; i<=lastTextViewTag; i++) {
      UITextView *newTextView = (UITextView *)[self.view viewWithTag:i]; 
      //or [yourCustomView viewWithTag:i]
      newTextView.text = textField.text;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

So first of all `delegate` is a pattern heavy used by iOS here is a [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-design-patterns-delegation-part-2-2) that will explain the basic concept of `delegate`.

Second, some of the UI controls that iOS provide have a delegate instance (after you read the above tutorial you will understand why and how it's working). A class can be a delegate of a custom UI control only if the class implements the required methods that the delegate provides (NOTE: there are optional methods also in the delegate), if the class doesn't implement the required methods a build warning will be shown at the line where the delegate is set.

Third, the method used in this answer are delegate methods of the UITextFiled [(check apple docs)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html)

I lost count, `[tag][3]` is a property available for all UIViews of subclasses of UIView that can be used to identify an object, but be careful that this property by default is **0** so make sure when you set the tag property you will use a value > 0.

For more details please use `google` and `Apple Docs`

Comment: OK, this is a little above me right now.  I am still new at this.  Can  you explain in simpler terms please.