# UITextfield doesn't show right part of the text (I see "..." symbols instead)

Tags: ios, ios7, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have UIVIewController for chatting. I want to insert smile text into textfield. And I want the right part of the text to be always visible.

But when the textfield is not the first responder, I see "..." at the right part of the textfield. For me it would be better to see "..." at the left part of the textfield (or not to see it at all), because when user enters smiles, he need to see what he entered.

[image]

I tried `self.textFieldMain.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;` , but it didn't help

**Update**

For now the best idea I found is to set only right part of text to textfield when it's not the first responder and to set the whole text when it's the first responder. But may be there is a better solution?

Comment: Why aren't you resizing the text field to fit the content?

Comment: because it's against the design

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is very similar to the problems posted on SO earlier. Please take a look at those solutions:

- [not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119365/uitextfield-not-scrolling-horizontally/20058992#20058992)
- [cursor always at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782664/uitextfield-functionality-with-no-keyboard)

It looks like there are nice workarounds for that case

Comment: self.textFieldMain.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight; doens't help for me