# Email Address Validation in IOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, email

I have contact form in my application in that i need to validate the email id i have found some solution for validating the email id but when used the validation method its showing warning.

```
@synthesize mail;
```

email validation code:

```
-(BOOL) Emailvalidate:(NSString *)mail
{
    BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:mail];
}
```

In the return its showing the warning like

> Local declaration of mail hides instance variable.

I am sending all the date's to my server using the `JSON` please tell me how to resolve this one.

Comment: The problem is you have an local variable (declared in your object) with the same name as the variable declared in your method, try to change (NSString *)mail to (NSString *)tempMail

Comment: @ReeCube i have changed the name now how to connect this validation to mail string

Comment: This is because of you have declare the same variable name in global scope.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you have an local variable *(declared in your object with @syntensize)* with the same name as the variable declared in your method, try this:

```
-(BOOL) validateEmail:(NSString *)tempMail
 {
     BOOL stricterFilter = YES;
     NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
     NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
     NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
     NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
     return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:tempMail];
 }
```

Comment: how to connect my  mail uitextfield and the validation pls tell me

Comment: Add an change event and then each time the content changes, you have to check it, more about the change event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Answer (score 1):

Well, your Emailvalidate method takes the parameter named 'mail', and your class already has a field named 'mail' as well... Just change the 'mail' parameter to something like 'newMail'..

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)validateEmailWithString:(NSString*)checkString {
    BOOL stricterFilter = NO;
    NSString *stricterFilterString = @"[A-Z0-9a-z\\._%+-]+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
    NSString *laxString = @".+@([A-Za-z0-9-]+\\.)+[A-Za-z]{2}[A-Za-z]*";
    NSString *emailRegex = stricterFilter ? stricterFilterString : laxString;
    NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegex];
    return [emailTest evaluateWithObject:checkString];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what cania already said, this would make a good class method instead of an instance method. I would make it a class method so that any of your classes can call it easily if you ever need to validate another e-mail.

Then a call would look like this and return true if a valid e-mail, assuming your mail property is a NSString.

```
if ([YourClassName Emailvalidate:self.mail]) {
      // valid e-mail, do what you want to do 
} 
else {
      // handle getting an invalid e-mail here 
}
```