# Is there a delegate call for when the text is changed on a UITextView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

When I set my `UITextView` programmatically like this:

`[self.textView setText:@""];`

The delegate method `textViewDidChange:` does not get called.  Is there a way I can find that *without* making a `UITextView` subclass?

Comment: the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59829100/294884

Comment: `insertText()`, however, does invoke `textViewDidChange`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When manually setting the text of a `UITextView` with code, the `textViewDidChange:` method does not get called. (If you have your text view's `delegate` set, it will get called when the user edits it, though.)

One possible workaround would be to manually call `textViewDidChange:` anytime you edit the text. For example:

```objectivec
[self.textView setText:@""];
[self textViewDidChange:self.textView];
```

Kind of a hackish way of doing it, but it gets the job done.

Comment: It's an interesting approach. Mostly, people don't consider calling delegate methods of frameworks manually. However, it's a nice idea.

Comment: Definitely not hackish, IMO. Methods are meant to be called and this one is staring you right in the face.

Comment: I think that it's safer to use `[self.textView.delegate textViewDidChange:self.textView]`, in case the `delegate` changes to a different object than `self`.

Answer (score 9):

I upvoted @rebello95's response because it is one approach. But another, less hacky approach is to do as

```objectivec
- (void)whereIManuallyChangeTextView
{//you don't actually have to create this method. It's simply wherever you are setting the textview to empty
  [self.textView setText:@""];
  [self respondToChangeInTextView:self.textView];
}
    
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
  //...some work and then
  [self respondToChangeInTextView:textView];
}
    
- (void)respondToChangeInTextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
  //what you want to happen when you programmatically/manually or interactively change the textview
}
```

This snippet exemplifies a respectable pattern that will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 4):

In swift you could override the `text` variable from the `UITextView` class:

```swift
class MyTextView: UITextView {

    override public var text: String? {
        didSet {
            self.textViewDidChange(self)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this wont work cause it doesnt get called when the user is typing

Comment: It should only enhance the textview to call the delegate whenever text is changed through code @LucasChwe

Answer (score 2):

Old post, but I had the same problem and thought I would share my solution (in Swift).

`textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)` does not get called by just setting the text property, but it does get called when using `replace(range: UITextRange, withText: String)`. So you need to create a UITextRange for the entire string of the UITextView and replace it with a new string.

```swift
// Create a range of entire string
let textRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.endOfDocument)
// Create a new string
let newText = ""
// Call Replace the string in your textView with the new string
textView.replace(textRange!, withText: newText)
```

That should do it. Of course, you need to set up UITextViewDelegate for this to work:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
```

Comment: tried this, but using textView.replace does not call the delegate for me

Answer (score 0):

You could also subclass UITextView and override setText to include

> [self textViewDidChange:self.textView]

so that you don't have to call it every time you set the text of your UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

delegate method `textDidChange` does not respond to programmatical changes in textes, you can use observation to get notified

1. declare your text view variable with `@objc dynamic`
2. declare and hold a variable with type `NSKeyValueObservation`
3. use function `observe(_:changeHandler:)` bind your text view's text property, hold the return value with variable declared in step 2
4. observe changes in changeHandler

example:

```
@objc dynamic private var textView: UITextView!
private var observation: NSKeyValueObservation?

func bind() {
    observation = observe(\.textView.text, options: [.old, .new]) { object, change in
        print(object, change)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this instead: (**this won't reset the current text**)

```
[self.textView insertText:@"something"];
```

this will call the delegate and will add text where the cursor is. Of course if you want to reset the whole text you can either:

```
[self.textView setText:@""];
[self textViewDidChange:self.textView];
```

or

```
[self.textView setText:@""];
[self.textView insertText:@"something"];
```

Comment: insertText doesn't call the delegate. 
Also: "textViewDidChange:
Discussion

The text view calls this method in response to user-initiated changes to the text. This method is not called in response to programmatically initiated changes." via: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextviewdelegate#jumpTo_7