# How to set a selector method to a textfield for textchange in objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, validation, uitextfield

I'm writing a signup view controller for my app. I needed to validate the form. I got the idea that setting a selector method for text value change should work for different textfields containing the form data. 
I saw old questions and stuff on google and this is what I have so far

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.passwordInput.secureTextEntry = YES;
    self.btnDone.enabled = NO; //Done button needs to be disabled until form is properly validated
    self.emailInput.delegate = self; //emailinput is the property attached to Email textfield of the form
    self.passwordInput.delegate = self;
    emailCheck = NO;
    passwordCheck = NO;
    [self.emailInput addTarget:self action:@selector(formValidation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.passwordInput addTarget:self action:@selector(formValidation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void) formValidation {

    NSString *regex = @"[^@]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]+";
    NSPredicate *emailPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", regex];
    if(self.passwordInput.text.length >7)
    {
        passwordCheck = YES;
    }
    if([emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:self.emailInput.text])
    {
        emailCheck = YES;
    }
    if (self.passwordInput.text.length<7 || ![emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:self.emailInput])
    {
    self.warningLabel.text = @"Please enter a valid email/at least 8 character password";
    }
    if(passwordCheck == YES && emailCheck ==YES)
    {
        self.btnDone.enabled = YES;//button is enabled
    } }
```

Now the problem is that the event is not firing off. Nothing happens when enter the data. Can anyone guide me what I'm doing wrong here?
P.s. i don't quite understand `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`. If someone can suggest an alternative solution or explain that concept for me, it'd be awesome
I just tried `forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged`, the app crashes with error that it can't perform regular expression.`**"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object <UITextField: 0x9ae8610;"**`

Comment: Look at the second non-accepted answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Comment: Did you include UITextfieldDelegate in header file?

Comment: Delegate is not required if you are using NSNotifications

Comment: use UIControlEventEditingChanged instead  UIControlEventValueChanged

Comment: I just used it. Please see above for the error I got.

Comment: The formValidation method will trigger an alert each time a character is entered. This will cause problems. Instead you should use the method when the editing ends.

Comment: Sorry for being completely dumb ZeMoon, but i think you are telling me to connect the selector method to "Sent Event" editingDidEnd in textfield menu? I got that right? Somehow i can't drag the connector chord from that Sent Even menu to the selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the delegate of textfields and use the following method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  [self validateForm:textField.text];
}
```

and change form validator function to

```
-(void) validateForm:(NSString *)inputString {

//validate inputString

}
```

Comment: It is the same error with UIControlEventEditingChanged. 2014-10-15 17:47:24.435 Mazeltov[2699:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object <UITextField: 0x998d950; frame = (121 116; 169 30); text = 'dawdwd'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM;

Comment: change the line [emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:self.emailInput] to [emailPredicate evaluateWithObject:self.emailInput.text] and then tell me.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. That was so embarrassing. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

on button submit click of form even you can check validation like below.

```
 - (IBAction)pushToSignConfirmationScreen:(id)sender;
 {
     NSString *emailString = txt_Email.text;// storing the entered email in a string.
   / / Regular expression to checl the email format.
     NSString *emailReg = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";

    NSPredicate *emailTest=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailReg];

     if ([txt_ContactName.text length] == 0 || [txt_Address.text length] == 0
       || [txt_DBAName.text length] == 0 || [txt_City.text length] == 0
       || [txt_Email.text length] == 0 || [txt_Phone.text length] == 0
      || [txt_State.text length] == 0)
      {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"All fields are required to begin setting up a merchant account." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
       [alert show];

      return;
   }

  else if(([emailTest evaluateWithObject:emailString]!=YES)||[emailString isEqualToString:@""])
  {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Enter your email in abc@example.com format." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    txt_Email.text = @"";
    [btn_next setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tag_icon_bt_up1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    return;
}
else if([txt_ZipCode.text length]!=5)
{
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please enter a valid zip code." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

      txt_ZipCode.text = @"";
     return;
  }
  else if([txt_Phone.text length]!=10 )
  {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please enter a       valid mobile number." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
      [alert show];

      txt_Phone.text = @"";
      return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but yeah it is simpler to validate the data on submission. My app requires the submission button to disabled until the Data passes the validation tests. I have applied the regex, as you can see above.

Comment: In textfieldDidEndEditing you can check validation for email & password text field & then if its true then enable submit button.

Answer (score 0):

First set the delegate for textfield, then do check in Method:-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField.
```

If `textField` is same then call your `formValidation` method.