# Auto check textfield length and Hit a method UITextfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

Hello I need to enter mobile number with validation that mobile textfield range should be 10.
And when textfield value ==10, i need to call a function when mobile textfield.text length becomes 10.
My below code work fine but i need to press 1 more character (means 11) to call it.
Please how i resolve it.

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField==user_mobile_txtField) 
   {


        if (textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH && range.length == 0)
        {

            if (textField.text.length==MAX_LENGTH) 
            {

                NSLog(@“Want to call Call method HERE ");

            }


            return NO; // return NO to not change text
        }


    }
     return YES;
}
```

Comment: Use the notification mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called just before actual text has changed. If you want to perform an action after actual text has changed, you can try the approach below:

```
...
//start observing
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textHasChanged:) name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification object:{your UITextField}];
...

- (void)textHasChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    UITextField *textField = [notification object];
    //check if textField.text.length >= 10
    //do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get what the string will be after the characters are changed with the method `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:`

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == user_mobile_txtField) {
        NSString *fullString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

        if (fullString.length >= MAX_LENGTH && range.length == 0) {
            if (fullString.length == MAX_LENGTH) {
                NSLog(@“Want to call Call method HERE ");
            }
            return NO; // return NO to not change text
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below code -

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 10

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField==user_mobile_txtField) 
   {


        if (textField.text.length >= MAX_LENGTH )
        {

            if (textField.text.length==MAX_LENGTH) 
            {

                NSLog(@“Want to call Call method HERE ");

            }


            return NO; // return NO to not change text
        }


    }
     return YES;
}
```