# How can I get the length of text entered into UITextView as the user types?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a`UITextView`. I would like to have a way of updating a`UILabel` as the user times to indicate how many remaining characters are permitted?

In the`ViewController` the`UITextView` is referenced as
`IBOutlet UITextView *message;`

I have tried looking at the show connections inspector and I don't see an edit changed option.

I looked at this example [UITextField text change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event)

But it seemed to apply to`UITextField` not`UITextView`

Comment: [`[<UITextViewDelegate> textViewDidChange:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidChange:)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

    NSString *stringCount = self.textView.text;
    int count = (int) stringCount.length;
    //assumes you have a label, see the attached gif
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TextView count is: %d",count];

    NSString *stringcount222 = self.textview222.text;
    int count222 = (int) stringcount222.length;
    self.label222.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No. 2 count is: %d", count222]; 

}
```

You need to select the TextView that you are using and `control+drag` to the ViewController icon and select Delegate:

[image]

The you should be able to get a result like this:

[image]

Comment: Awesome job. Really helpful!

Comment: How does it know which textview?

Comment: you can declare which textview by referencing it. self.yourTextView1.text, self.yourTextview2.text, etc.

Comment: @JackShultz Just tested, you need to control+drag to the view controller icon on story board and select "delegate" on the TextViews

Comment: @JackShultz simply change the name of either the self.textviews to yours: `NSString * wordcount = self.message.text` - check the updated answer for more help.