# enable button if textfield is filled in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I have a few text fields in my iOS app and need to disable a button until all fields are filled.

Hope someone here can help me with that code and where it should go.

Here is what I have tried but not getting right. It seems to not run the enable button command.

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var panelWidthTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var panelHightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var panelsWideTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var panelsHightTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var panelPitchTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var calculateButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var resultWithLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resultHightLabel: UILabel!


// Removes keyboard when touch outside edit field.
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?){
    view.endEditing(true)
    super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}


func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {


    if ((panelWidthTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) && (panelsWideTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) && (panelHightTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) && (panelPitchTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil)){
        self.calculateButton.enabled = false
    }else{
        self.calculateButton.enabled = true
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    panelWidthTextField.delegate = self
    panelsWideTextField.delegate = self
    panelHightTextField.delegate = self
    panelsHightTextField.delegate = self
    panelPitchTextField.delegate = self




}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // Hideo button


}

func calculatePressButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let w = Double(panelWidthTextField.text!)
    let sw = Double(panelsWideTextField.text!)
    let pi = Double(panelPitchTextField.text!)
    let sizew = SizeWidthModel(pw:w!,psw:sw!,ptc:pi!)
    resultWithLabel.text=String(sizew.width())

    let h = Double(panelHightTextField.text!)
    let sh = Double(panelsHightTextField.text!)
    let sizeh = SizeHightModel(ph:h!,psh:sh!,ptc:pi!)
    resultHightLabel.text=String(sizeh.hight())
```

}

```
}
```

All I get when starting to fill inn fields is this.
[erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwPWh.png)

Appreciate any help. :-)

Comment: what is `void;  textFieldDidChange;:(UITextField*)textField` supposed to be? That does not look like working code to me.

Comment: @lightmaster2006 Are  you looking for swift?

Comment: @luk2302 That where I stopped, it´s not a working code and that is why I am asking for help on this swift project.

Comment: but what is the `didChange` function doing there? Your code probably makes the question less understandable... create an IBAction for the textfields and connect them as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13729112/2442804) - your logic for the lengths seem correct.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly set delegate to all your text field and then implement this method

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        if ((panelWidthTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) && (panelsWideTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) && (panelHightTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil) && (panelPitchTextField.text?.isEmpty != nil)){
            self.calculateButton.enabled = true
        }else{
            self.calculateButton.enabled = false
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that got me closer to what I need :-) But can you explain to me how and where to set delegates?

Comment: @lightmaster2006 panelWidthTextField.delegate = self and put same code for all text field.

Comment: @ Mukesh Chaudhry but where do I put it in the code? See the whole code above.

Comment: @lightmaster2006 put it in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now but it still does not what I want. The whole idea is to make sure the button is not enabled before all fields are fille in. At the moment it does not do anything.

Comment: @lightmaster2006 remove cursor from last text field it will work

Comment: Chaudhry I think my problem is that I have the button as IBOutlet and Action? or am I wrong?

Comment: @lightmaster2006 Yes you need to connect your button with your IBOutlet

Comment: @ Mukesh Chaudhry Can you please look true my whole code and see if you find som error, There is something making the app crash when I test.