# iOS:Keyboard's head which is store associational word, if I click the word, which method is listening the click event?

Tags: ios, keyboard, textfield

As the title: `Keyboard's` head which is store associational word, if I click the word, which `method` is listening the `click event`?

I have tested `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, `textFieldDidEndEditing:`, `textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:`, nor them. Which method is listening the `word click event`?

Comment: did you also checked UIControlEventEditingChanged ? Please have a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad U helped me, how can I upvote you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try `UIControllEventEditingChanged`.

Please have a look at below question and its answers:

[UITextField text change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event)