# How to enable a button when all textfield is filled

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitextfield

Initially `button.isHidden = true`, however, I would like to set the `button.isHidden = false`, when all textfields are filled. Where should I put the If-Else condition in, most probably not in `viewDidLoad`, please advise.

Comment: Please provide what you tried, and most importantly, your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this post [UITextField text change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event)
and then in textFieldDidChange function you should check texts of each textfield

Comment: I found the solution through the idea you gave.