# UITextField Delegate "shouldChangeCharactersIn" not called for first entry in textfield

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am building a view which accepts 4 digit OTP. The code I have is as follows

"CodeText" is subclass of UITextField

```
    class RegisterController: ModelController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var firstDigit:CodeText?
    @IBOutlet var secondDigit:CodeText?
    @IBOutlet var thirdDigit:CodeText?
    @IBOutlet var fourthDigit:CodeText?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        self.firstDigit!.delegate = self
        self.secondDigit!.delegate = self
        self.thirdDigit!.delegate = self
        self.fourthDigit!.delegate = self

        self.firstDigit!.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    // UITextField Delegate Methods

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


        if (textField == self.firstDigit) {

            if(textField.text!.characters.count >= 1 ) {

                self.secondDigit?.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else if (textField == secondDigit) {

            if(textField.text!.characters.count >= 1 ) {

                self.thirdDigit?.becomeFirstResponder()
            }

        }
        else if (textField == thirdDigit) {

            if(textField.text!.characters.count >= 1 ) {

                self.fourthDigit?.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else if (textField == fourthDigit) {

            print("Fourth Digit")

            if(textField.text!.characters.count >= 1 ) {

                self.fourthDigit?.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Above code works fine for me except for one feature. I want the keyboard to be dismissed after fourth digit entry, but what's happening is the "shouldChange" delegate method is not called when the "fourthDigit" get it's focus and get it's first entry but the delegate is called when the textfield gets it's second entry and the keyboard is getting dismissed.

So in order to get the keyboard dismissed an unnecessary keystroke is needed.

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: why you are not tried with `Editing Changed` instead of `shouldChangeCharactersIn`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternate choice for capture all event of your text field, with out coding

- Cretae a IBAction (in your Current textfield VC)
- Ctrl-Click (or right click) on the UITextField in Interface Builder
- Connect the "Editing Changed" event to the File's Owner's IBAction added in the first step.

for e.g your `UIControlEventEditingChanged` method name is `updateContentsOfTextField`

and get output in

```
func updateContentsOfTextField(_ theTextField: UITextField) {
print("text changed: \(theTextField.text)")
}
```

you can get the more information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event)

Answer (score 0):

Please try `string.length>0` instead of `textField.text!.characters.count >= 1`

**EDIT**

I've managed to get callback when user enters a character in `textfield` using a notification

```
// in your respective method where you init your text field
[_txtSearchLocation addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

- (void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *) textField{
}
```

When this method gets call you can call `textField.resignFirstResponder`

Sorry for Obj-c, i copied this from my current open file thx

Comment: The issue is the method itself is not getting called. Changing the condition will not help in this case. Thanks for your response

Comment: i guess you're not missing setting delegate for your last `textfield`

Comment: The delegate is set and the methods´is called when second entry is entered in the textfield