# Changing programmatically the text of a text field

Tags: ios, string, replace, swift3, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` where I need to replace certain characters the user may type with different ones (for example, I need to append a suffix to the text that has been entered by the user if he has tapped a space), and show the result to the user in such `UITextField`.

I'm trying to directly set `textField.text = "my text"` when I am notified that the text in the text field has changed, but it is not working. In the examples I have found, the text in the text field is not changed, it is only checked for certain characters without modifying `texField.text`

How could I change the text in a text field in code, and show there the result?

Comment: Which method you are updating the textfield value with yours? is it in side the textfield delegate?

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
    if string == " "
    {
        textField.text?.append("q")
    }
    return true
}
```

Add UITextFieldDelegate to your ViewController and

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from you question.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTextDidChange(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
```

[Check this link for more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998918/3589771)

You will get updated textfield text in this function. If you find anything char which you want to change replace or append anything here.