# shouldChangeCharactersInRange behaves strange

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am using following `textfield delegate` to validate user entry.

Lets assume that `currentTotal` equals `30.00` dollars and whenever user enters `two times` equal or bigger than `currentTotal` and I am trying to issue an alert.

While I am testing the application, when user enters `63` dollars, no alert happens, but as long as user enters `630` dollars then alert is issued.

`tip` and `currentTotal` are `double`.

What am I doing wrong, any suggestions?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)aTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{    
    if ([aTextField.text containsString:@"$"])
    {
        tip = [[aTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""] doubleValue];
    }
    else
    {
        tip = [aTextField.text doubleValue];
    }

    if(tip > currentTotal *2)
    {
      [self presentViewController:[AppConstant oneButtonDisplayAlert:@"Error" withMessage:@"Please enter valid tip"] animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.tipTF.text = @"$ ";
}
```

Comment: whats your currentTotal

Comment: It is 30.00, double.

Comment: convert double to integerValue and check once

Comment: I need to keep double. When I am debugging, even though on the text field I see `63`, but in the delegate method I see `tip` value is `6`. When I add one more digit to make it `630`, then I see tip value is `63` and then it issues an alert.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433337/set-the-maximum-character-length-of-a-uitextfield

Comment: Could you please specify the issue on my implementation?

Comment: sure give 2 minutes

Comment: Please show the code to set `currentTotal` and where it is located.

Comment: `currentTotal = 30.00` is hardcoded at the moment in the `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You seem to be missing the fact that `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called *before* the text is changed. You are checking the value before the update is made. Use your debugger and step through the code. And why, based on my answer to your last question, are you hardcoding a `$` symbol instead of using a `NumberFormatter` to properly parse and format currency values entered by the user?

Comment: I am using `NumberFormatter` instead. Based on your comment, this delegate is getting called before it updates the `texfield` that makes sense based on when the value of the `textfield` when I was debugging. Therefore, I wonder what delegate is appropriate to handle this issue.

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event

Answer (score 3):

The method you use is `-textView:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacement`. The *should* means that the action is on to be done, but not be done yet. Therefore getting the value from the text field, you will get the old value.

If you want to know the new value, you have to replace the replacement in your method yourself (make a copy of the string value).

```
NSString *newValue = [aTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
double tip = [newValue doubleValue]; // Where does your var tip comes from?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if (textField == self.tipTF)
    {
        if (self.tipTF.text && self.tipTF.text.length > 0) {
            [textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
    NSLog( @"text changed: %@", theTextField.text);
    double tip;
    if ([theTextField.text containsString:@"$"])
    {
        tip = [[theTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"$" withString:@""] doubleValue];
    }else {
        tip = [theTextField.text doubleValue];
    }

    if (tip > currentTotal *2) {
        [self presentViewController:[AppConstant oneButtonDisplayAlert:@"Error" withMessage:@"Please enter valid tip"] animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not setup the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event in the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method. That's just wrong. Why would your keep calling `addTarget` every time the text field's value is about to change?

Comment: @rmaddy, then what do you suggest? The proposed solution works `textFieldDidChange` is getting called.

Comment: Setup the text field once in viewDidLoad.