# how can i detect that how much time the cursor was blinking - ios - swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to detect cursor blinking in swift 4?

Actually, I wanna call the specific function after the user finished their editing, not while editing. i have used the function `textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {}`, `func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {}` and all related functionalities. Those functionalities are called when the user typed 1 word but actually, I want to call the function after they typed the full words or chars they want.

Comment: here in Objective-c https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010547/uitextfield-text-change-event  use notification.  Or simply call didEndEdting delegate of textfield. You can detect edit end of your textfield.

Comment: without any button clicked I wanna know the words they entered. didEndEdting will call after the done button clicked.

Comment: @RohiniG - you get the exact OP from shouldChangeCharactersIn

Comment: yup but not the exact one. please reconsider my need.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. When that fires, you'll know that there hasn't been any text input for whatever timeout value you choose:

```
private var timer: Timer?

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   self.timer?.invalidate()
   self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { _ in
       // this is called 1 second after the last entry in the textfield
   }
   return true
}
```

Comment: is there any chance to get the user's input without any time delay? because say, if they type 4 chars means it won't take 1sec.

Comment: Without the delay, you won't know if the user has actually stopped typing, and might as well use `shouldChangeCharactersIn` directly. If 1 sec seems to long, you're free to change it to smaller values.

Comment: okay. Nope, I won't call shouldChangeCharactersIn because I need the complete word. so, i took that from the _ textField. your answer is seems to be very useful. Thank you so much. +1.

Comment: you have any idea about autocompletetextview as a solution for this task. autocomplete won't call during typing it will call after finished the typing without any delay.